# Random OWIN/OpenID behavior on ASP.NET 4.8 app startup - user sometimes is redirected to Azure automatically

Tags: asp.net, owin, openid, .net-4.8

Weird behavior.

My application allows authentication via both internal accounts (using ASP.NET Identity) and Azure AD. The idea is that the login screen is shown and the user decides which way.

But sometimes, completely randomly, the first request is automatically redirected to Azure AD for authentication. I'd say 1 out of 4 times i start debugging the application and this happens.

I added logs to my HomeController and i know that, during these times the user is redirected automatically, the Controller constructor has never even been called.

This is my Startup.Auth.cs file:

```cs
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager(),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });

        var azureAdTenant = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAD:TenantId"];
        var azureAdClientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAD:ClientId"];
        var azureAdRedirectUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAD:RedirectUri"];
        var azureAdPostLogoutRedirectUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAD:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
        var azureAdAuthority = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAD:Authority"], azureAdTenant);


        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions("AzureAD")
            {
                ClientId = azureAdClientId,
                Authority = azureAdAuthority,
                RedirectUri = azureAdRedirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = azureAdPostLogoutRedirectUri,
                Scope = "openid profile User.Read",
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters(),
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                    {
                        // Check if it's the auth request we need to modify
                        if (context.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication)
                        {
                            // Add the extra scope for Graph
                            context.ProtocolMessage.Scope += " https://graph.microsoft.com/Group.Read.All";
                        }

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
                    {
                        // MSAL Confidential Client setup
                        var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(azureAdClientId)
                            .WithClientSecret(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAD:AppSecret"])
                            .WithRedirectUri(azureAdRedirectUri)
                            .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{azureAdTenant}/"))
                            .Build();

                        // Acquiring token using the authorization code
                        var result = await confidentialClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }, context.ProtocolMessage.Code)
                            .ExecuteAsync();

                        // Creating an identity for the user and adding claims
                        var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

                        appIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:tokens:access_token", result.AccessToken));
                        appIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, context.JwtSecurityToken.Subject));
                        if (context.JwtSecurityToken.Claims.Any(c => c.Type == "groups"))
                            appIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("hasGroups", "true"));

                        var externalIdentity = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                        externalIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:tokens:access_token", result.AccessToken));

                        // Sign in the user
                        context.OwinContext.Authentication.SignIn(appIdentity);
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }

    private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private Task OnAuthenticationSucceeded(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why yet, but this "AuthenticationMode" parameter solved the issue:

```cs
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions("AzureAD")
    {
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
    }
);
```